# What's happening with the 2nd element of the array?

Tags: c#

Suppose I write

```
int numbers[] = {1,2,3};
ref int second = ref numbers[1];
Array.Resize(ref numbers, 1);
Console.WriteLine(second); // works fine
second = 321; // also legit
```

How does this work? Have I magically allocated `numbers[1]` as a separate, addressable number on the managed heap? What's going on here?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is here? You're just using pointers?

Comment: I took his question to mean "what happened to `ref int second` here" since his array now only contains the `[0]` index, so how did `ref int second` still work, since it points to the `[1]` element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Array.Resize` creates a new array, leaving the old one on the heap, as per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method **allocates a new array** with the specified size, **copies elements** from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one.

*(my emphasis)*

**Note**: The documentation is slightly misleading depending on how you understand it. It says "then replaces the old array with the new one". What it means is that it replaces the **reference** you have in the array variable, `numbers` in your example, with a reference to the new array. The old array *object* is left intact and untouched in memory.

If you didn't have a `ref int` reference into it, GC would eventually pick it up, but since you do, it doesn't.

`second = 321` changes the *original* array, not the new one.

You can easily show this using a very simple example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        int[] b = a;
        ref int a1 = ref a[1];

        Array.Resize(ref a, 5);

        a1 = 100;
        Console.WriteLine(a[1]); // new
        Console.WriteLine(b[1]); // original
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a, b));
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
2            // the new array, which did not change
100          // the original array, which did change
false        // not the same arrays
```

So the `ref int` variable did change, and the original array *did* change, but the new, size-modified, copy did not.

[See this example on .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Li8eX)

Answer (score 3):

> This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one.array must be a one-dimensional array.
>
> If array is null, this method creates a new array with the specified size.
>
> If newSize is greater than the Length of the old array, a new array is allocated and all the elements are copied from the old array to the new one. If newSize is less than the Length of the old array, a new array is allocated and elements are copied from the old array to the new one until the new one is filled; the rest of the elements in the old array are ignored. If newSize is equal to the Length of the old array, this method does nothing.

Straight from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx)